# Margins different between Chrome and Mozilla

Tags: css, positioning, margins

I'm stuck on a margin/positioning issue where I have a div that will not cooperate between Mozilla and Webkit browsers. The element in question is at the bottom of the page http://clifford-stage.scholastic.com/Calendar where there is a black box with a top-right-border with a radius. (editor's note about posters...) In mozilla the border does not break past the bottom edges and displays as desired, however in Chrome and Safari, the bottom flows past the edge, and I've played with every margin scenario but cannot seem to get it to agree between browsers.

I'd appreciate any help. (BTW, this is NOT my page design...)

Comment: btw, setting a webkit specific style sheet selector did not work, i.e. -webkit-margin-top:xxpx;

Comment: i dont think `-webkit-margin-top` is actually a CSS property... and you don't explicitly set an X&Y value. firefox borks at `position:absolute` when you dont set the X&Y coordinates, i.e. `top:0; left:0;` or something.

Comment: OK, I've seen the browser specific properties though, like to get a certain browser to understand what another understands differently. But perhaps I'm typing it in wrong? Also, what x&Y coordinates are we referring to. I did not build this page, I'm just tasked to make edits, which I added the black content box (div id="editorsNote") and also have some z-index issues to deal with too (another post). I totally want to scrap this page and rebuild it because I don't have the slightest clue as to what the code objective is...tables?!?! Anyway, thanks for helping if you can.

Comment: X&Y = `top` / `bottom` and `left` / `right` declarations. u just declare `position:absolute` but a proper declaration is `position:absolute; top:0; left:0` ... something that has locations explicitly declared on the X and Y axes.

Comment: actually not table-based, my correction..that was another page I'm thinking of.

Comment: ill add it as an answer so u can give me the checkmark.

Answer (score 3):

With Firefox, you need to explicitly declare X & Y coordinates when using `position:absolute;`:

```
#yourDiv {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Otherwise you will get quirky behavior. It is also proper browser behavior, Firefox is just stricter about it than Chrome is.